# How do I enable JavaScription wordpress so that a Streamlit app runs on an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, streamlit

I have created an app in Streamlit and I'm trying to integrate it to wordpress. I'm currently trying to embed an iframe with a custom HTML block. The extern javascript code (from streamlit) seems not to be loading.

I tried creating an HTML block with:

```
<style>
    iframe {
      border: none;
    }
  </style>


  <iframe src="https://share.streamlit.io/cromato/manabase/main/main.py" width="100%" height="500" allowfullscreen="" sandbox="">

  </iframe>
```

And I'm getting only "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." as output when I preview or load the site.

Comment: I checked your link, is the "Mana Base Calculator" you want to display ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To embed Streamlit apps, you have to add "?embedded=true" at the end of the source.
You need to add some values on your sandbox attribute : "allow-scripts" and "allow-same-origin".
Here is the result :

```
     <style>
        iframe {
          border: none;
        }
      </style> 
<iframe src="https://cromato-manabase-main-5f3sfp.streamlit.app/?embedded=true" width="100%" height="500" allowfullscreen="" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin">
     </iframe>
```